Is the Eth network congested?
Showed confirmed on metamask but not pending or anything on blockchain. It should’ve been in my wallet by now right?

It is working as expected. As of 2024-11-09 18:48:00 UTC gas price average is 6.8 gwei. Metamask uses a webservice to track transaction so perhaps the service isn't working. Which network are you using? What is the transaction id?
